# How to get filtered sharepoint list item using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

**I am using REST Api to get sharepoint List items.**

**Now I am trying to retrieve all filtered list items where status is completed.**

But i was getting 400 request error

I was fire query like below.

```
https://MySiteName/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

Comment: The query you fired should work. Make sure, that the listname ('MyList') is correct and make sure the column Status is really called Status and the field value is really called Completed. Also you could first check it without everthing after /items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally i got  solution i am passing in URL so URL never contain white space it so i change like this and its work for me**

```
https://MySiteName/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=Status+eq+'Completed'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code its working for me,

```
     /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status$filter=Status eq 'Completed'


    /_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/Items?$select=Title,ID,Status$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it, and in my environment it is working. SharePoint 2013 on-prem.

Listname:

> MyList

Columns:

> Title (by default included)
>
> ID (by default included)
>
> Status ->
>   Dropdown -> Fieldvalues -> Open, Completed

[image]

After entering the query in browser I get:

[image]

As far as I understood here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/fp142380.aspx

It should not make a difference for your requirement. Snippet:

> To access a specific site collection, use the following construction:
>
> http://server/site/_api/site
>
> To access a specific site, use the following construction:
>
> http://server/site/_api/web

Comment: no its not work for me. dont know why

Comment: when i remove filter then its work well then its not give 400  error

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: As per Patrick, Please let us know which version of SharePoint (with Updates details ) are you using?

Comment: office 365 2013

Comment: To access via REST SharePoint Online you can take a look into this question asked already here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/consume-sharepoint-online-lists-using-rest-api-in-r also here is something: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130343/how-to-filter-for-files-using-rest-api-sharepoint-online

Comment: @Patrick i just want to that data of list which status is completed

Comment: Yes, I think you have to call it different in SharePoint Online. So those links should help

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be

```
https://MySiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 0):

https://MySiteName/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=Status eq 'Completed'

You missed 'web' before /lists/

https://MySiteName/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status&$filter=Status eq 'Completed'

Answer (score 0):

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$select=Title,ID,Status$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

you should remove **guid** before '' like this:

```
/_api/Web/Lists('GUID')/Items?$select=Title,ID,Status$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

for example :

```
 /_api/web/lists('%7B326038AE-D47E-454D-AAD4-5440E6133EF2%7D')
```